# BeautifulSoup - Links verdadeiros do href

Tags: html, python, web-scraping, scraping

Eu estava estudando sobre WebScraping com Python e comecei a utilizar a bilioteca bs4 (BeautifulSoup). Quando comecei a pegar as tags `a` e o atributo `href`, percebi que eu não poderia acessar o link se no `href` tivesse algo como:

```
href="/alguma_pagina.php"
```

No caso acima, não posso simplesmente fazer um request para o valor `"/alguma_coisa.php"`, pois isso não é uma url válida.

Eu preciso pegar a verdadeira url para onde eu irei ao clicar no link, não apenas o valor que está no href. Como eu consigo pegar essa url completa?

Lembrando que existe a possibilidade da url ser do tipo `"url.com.br/"` com ou sem a barra no final. Já os valores de href pode ser do tipo:

```
"#"
"#alguma_coisa"
"cadastro.php"
"/cadastro.php"
"http://outra_url.com"
"outra_url.com"
```

e cada um desses, pode começar ou terminar com um espaço.

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja com o seu tratamento/validação dos dados, a principio você esta conseguindo pegar a `URL` que deseja porém ela não esta formatada como você quer. Já tentou utilizar `regex` para validar as possíveis variações?

Comment: Quando eu tenho `outraurl.com` ou `qualquercoisa.jsp` não tem como usar regex pra determinar se é um link ou um arquivo. Eu pensei em criar um vetor com todos os domínios possíveis e ver se a string terminava com um deles, mas é muita gambiarra.

Comment: com `regex` você consegue sim ver se é uma `URL` tudo depende de como você aplicar as regras, e ao meu vêr não existe gambiarra no seu caso, se você precisa realizar uma validação muito especifica isso chega a ser normal, o que você pode fazer é procurar um `package` que faça uma validação mais limpa pra economizar linhas de código.

Answer (score 1):

Todas as vezes em que você está em uma página e nela há um link relativo o link corresponde a própria página mais a sua url.

Você pode usar a lib `urlparse` para que seja feia uma concatenação e fazer um novo request.

Porém, como você mesmo disse, as vezes a url não é relativa. Vamos tentar resolver esse caso:

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.urljoin('http://google.com', 'http://ddg.gg')
```

Nesse caso, como as duas urls são absolutas, ele vai usar sempre a segunda, para que você consiga manter uma url fixa no início e variar a segunda.

Um outro caso seria adicionar com a mesma função uma absoluta e uma relativa, por exemplo:

```
urllib.parse.urljoin('http://ddg.gg/', 'teste.php')
```

O retorno seria `'http://ddg.gg/teste.php'` o que mata o caso das urls relativas.

O único caso em que essa função não vai resolver é o caso de não haver o prefixo 'http' na segunda string, o que faria o mesmo juntar as duas strings:

```
urllib.parse.urljoin('http://ddg.com/', 'teste.com')
```

O retorno seria `'http://ddg.com/teste.com'` aí vai caber a você saber se a url é válida ou não.

Outra opção de usar o `urlparse`

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.urlparse('teste.com') 
# ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='teste.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Que nesse caso vai te devolver uma tupla nomeada que pode ser usada para ver o atributo `netloc`. Caso o mesmo não exista, significa que a url não é uma url absoluta. Isso resolve o mesmo caso do anterior, embora eu ache a primeira implementação mais pythonica.

No caso de a url ter um valor absurdo, porém sem o prefixo `http`, vai caber a você novamente. O que eu recomendaria, você pode criar uma lista com *badwords*. Uma lista que contenha os valores de sufixo da string, por exemplo, `['.com', '.net', '.br', '.de']` e fazer uma validação simples para ver se algum dos elementos dessa lista está contido na string, assim você saberia também que ela não é relativa e poderia usar isso de critério para fazer o request ou não.